# How to display data in PHP from multiple tables for a logged in user?

Tags: php, mysql

There are 2 tables

> student_info (username,firstname,lastname,password,email,contact age)

and

> student_course_info(username{fk},subject,beginner).

I want to display all the info for a logged in user.

```
 <?php

                $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","elearning");

                // Check connection
                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

                if (isset($_SESSION["username"]))
                {
                $_POST["username"]=$_SESSION["username"];
                $user=$_POST["username"];
                }

                $result = mysqli_query($con,""SELECT * FROM student_info , student_course_info 
                                              WHERE student_info.username=student_course_info.username
                                              AND student_info.username=$user AND student_course_info.username=$user
                                              "
                                              ");



            if($_SESSION["username"]) {

                echo "<table border='1'>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>username</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>First Name</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>Last Name Name</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>Email</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>contact</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['contact'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>Age</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>Subject</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['subject'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>Beginner</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['beginner'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>Level</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['level'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                }

                echo "</table>";

                }


                mysqli_close($con);


                ?>
```

It gives error at `$user`.I suppose that either sql query is wrong or logged in username is not getting stored in `$user`.

Comment: Why the double `"`? It's just a string, just like the others you used before.

Comment: put "or die(mysql_error());" at the end of the line concerning your sql querry

Comment: nd use the binding function for the username. [bind-param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student_info, student_course_info
                                WHERE
                                    student_info.username = '{$user}'
                                AND
                                    student_info.username = student_course_info.username
                      ");
```

Of course, you should use **prepared statements** instead of just building it on your own. That's the point of **MySQLi**.

Note that I used only one `"` and not `""` at the beginning and in the end of the query.
There's no point in checking `student_couse_info.username = '{$user}'` when you explicitely said it had to be the same as `student_course.username`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to

```
$strSQL = 'SELECT * FROM student_info , student_course_info 
WHERE student_info.username=student_course_info.username
AND student_info.username='.$user.' AND student_course_info.username='.$user.';';

$result = mysqli_query($con,$strSQL);

if(mysqli_errno($con)){ echo 'Query:'.$strSQL.' -- Error description:'. mysqli_error($con);}
```

I recommend you to save the query and if you got an error you could print it and see where the error is or execute it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong in your approach.

**Select statement via session**

Session data can be changed or stolen, this means that I don't need a password to get access to the user data.

- You should encrypt your session ( for example with sha1 or md5 ).
- Check your session with the current IP, so that you are sure that its not stolen.

**SQL injections**

When my username is OR 1=1--` I will get the following query.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  student_info, 
  student_course_info 
WHERE 
  student_info.username = student_course_info.username
AND 
  student_info.username=
OR
  1=1--
```

This means I will get all the information that I wanna have. U should use the bindings options that the msqli class has. Example:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT foo FROM foobar WHERE user = ? AND password = ?");
$stmt->bind_param(ss, $username, $password);
// ss says the input is a string.
```

See documentation for options

**Your Error**

In your script its probably the `""`. You close your string directly after you opening it so your query will not be parsed (  should even give a PHP error ).

Comment: Just one note: **SHA-1** and **MD5** are NOT encryption methods strictly speaking, they are **hashing** methods. They are **insecure** for handling sensitive data, as they have a great opportunity to find collisions. To handle sensitive data, you have to use something stronger, like `mcrypt_encrypt()` in PHP, that uses **AES-128** and above. Also note that hashing is a one-way method, you can't decrypt using it. More info: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

Answer (score -1):

```
Try it, select Database name


<?php

                $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");

                // Check connection
                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
mysql_select_db("elearning") or die(" error database");

                if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
                {
               $user= $_SESSION['username'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM student_info , student_course_info  WHERE student_info.username=student_course_info.username AND student_info.username='$user' AND student_course_info.username='$user'");

      echo "<table border='1'>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>username</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>First Name</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>Last Name Name</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>Email</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>contact</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['contact'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>Age</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>Subject</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['subject'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>Beginner</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['beginner'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>Level</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['level'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                }

                echo "</table>";

}

                mysqli_close($con);


                ?>
```